# How to prove that the following is a metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

## Problem

Let $M = (\mathbb{T}^2, d)$ where
$$
d(u, v) = 3 - [\cos(u_1 - v_1) + \cos(u_2 - v_2) + \cos((u_1 - v_1) - (u_2 - v_2))]
$$

Prove that $M$ is a metric space.

## Progress

So I know that axioms for a metric space are the following:

1. $d(u, v) = 0 \iff u = v$
2. $d(u, v) = d(v, u)$
3. $d(u, w) \le d(u, v) + d(v, w)$

I am able to prove axiom 1 and 2, however, the triangle inequality (axiom 3) is the one giving me the problem. I do not even know how to begin proving this. I am also not educated in real or complex analysis so I do not have the knowledge of those theories at my disposal. If a proof is given in those terms, however, I would be able to follow and understand. I can't off the top of my head figure out a proof using them though (if that makes any sense).

If it helps, the above metric was simplified (with a few changes) from the following:

- Let $h(s, t) = (\cos(s) - \cos(t))^2 + (\sin(s) - \sin(t))^2$ where $s,t \in \mathbb{T}$.

Then the metric is,

$$
d(u, v) = \sqrt{h(u_1, v_1) + h(u_2, v_2) + h(u_1 + v_1, u_2 + v_2)}
$$

Any and all help would be much appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: What is $\mathbb{T}^2$?

Comment: @Kumar $\mathbb{T}^2:=\mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{S}^1$ the 2-dimensional torus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#n-dimensional_torus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map $\Bbb T^2=\Bbb S^1\times \Bbb S^1\to\Bbb S^1\times \Bbb S^1\times \Bbb S^1$, $(u,v)\mapsto (u,v,u+v)$ and then each of the three $\Bbb S^1\to \Bbb R^2$, $u\mapsto (\cos u,\sin u)$ (during this, we identify $\Bbb S^1$ with $\Bbb R/2\pi\Bbb Z$). So in total you have a continuous injective map $\Bbb T^2\to \Bbb R^6$. Then $d$ is just the Euclidean metric on the image.

Comment: Yes, this was very helpful! Thank you very much!!